# copy d3d11texture from another device

Tags: windows, directx

**CopyResource is not woorking,everyone knows why?i have setted  GetSharedHandle and OpenSharedResource.

```
//desc1
m_desc.Width = rendererInfo.SrcBounds.Width;
m_desc.Height = rendererInfo.SrcBounds.Height;
m_desc.Format = rendererInfo.SrcFormat;
m_desc.ArraySize = 1;
m_desc.BindFlags = 0;
m_desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;
m_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
m_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
m_desc.MipLevels = 1;
m_desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
m_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
m_destdesc = m_desc;
//desc2
m_destdesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
m_destdesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
```

...

```
IDXGIResource* copyResource = nullptr;
hr = m_copyTexture2D->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&copyResource);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return false;

HANDLE shareHandle = nullptr;
hr = copyResource->GetSharedHandle(&shareHandle);
copyResource->Release();
copyResource = nullptr;
ID3D11Resource* tempResource = nullptr;
ID3D11Texture2D* tempTex2D = nullptr;
hr = m_device->OpenSharedResource(shareHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Resource), (void**)(&tempResource));
tempResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)(&tempTex2D));
ID3D11Device* ppDevice = nullptr;
tempTex2D->GetDevice(&ppDevice);
tempResource->Release();
//DirectX::SaveWICTextureToFile(m_deviceContext, tempTex2D, GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, L"d:/glinterop2.jpg");
ID3D11DeviceContext* tempContext = nullptr;
ppDevice->GetImmediateContext(&tempContext);
tempContext->CopyResource(m_destTexture2D, tempTex2D);
tempContext->Flush();
ID3D11DeviceContext* destContext = nullptr;
pContext->getCurrentD3D11Device()->GetImmediateContext(&destContext);
DirectX::SaveWICTextureToFile(destContext, m_destTexture2D, GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, L"d:/glinterop3.jpg");
//destContext->Release();
//tempTex2D->Release();
if (m_deskDupl) {
    hr = m_deskDupl->ReleaseFrame();
}**
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you checking the HRESULT values of every function that reutrns it?

Comment: Have you read through this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis) page?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I have solved this question~

Answer (score 0):

```
IDXGIResource* copyResource = nullptr;
hr = m_destTexture2D->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&copyResource);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return false;

HANDLE shareHandle = nullptr;
hr = copyResource->GetSharedHandle(&shareHandle);
copyResource->Release();
copyResource = nullptr;
ID3D11Texture2D* tempTex2D = nullptr;
hr = m_device->OpenSharedResource(shareHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)(&tempTex2D));

m_deviceContext->CopyResource(tempTex2D, m_copyTexture2D);
m_deviceContext->Flush();
ID3D11Device* ppDevice = nullptr;
tempTex2D->GetDevice(&ppDevice);
ID3D11DeviceContext* tempContext = nullptr;
ppDevice->GetImmediateContext(&tempContext);
DirectX::SaveWICTextureToFile(tempContext, tempTex2D, GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, L"d:/glinterop2.jpg");
tempTex2D->Release();
tempTex2D = nullptr;
tempContext->Release();
tempContext = nullptr;
ppDevice->Release();
ppDevice = nullptr;
DirectX::SaveWICTextureToFile(m_destContext, m_destTexture2D, GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, L"d:/glinterop3.jpg");

if (m_deskDupl) {
    hr = m_deskDupl->ReleaseFrame();
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.